# I have created small desktop application using PySimpleGUI and cx_oracle and created exe not working in another machine

Tags: pyinstaller

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os
import cx_Oracle

-----
code
-----
```

using pyinstaller I did created `.exe` file and it is working fine but in another machine having same configurations it is not working. could you please let me know exactly what software do we need to install in another machines as i am trying to connect oracle DB using `cx_oracle`. (DB exists in central server and everyone is having access)

Comment: I'm afraid you need to [edit] your question and include what "it is not working" exactly means - what error or error log can you see? Also it will be helpful to specify the dependencies you used when creating your application?

Comment: Is the other machine running a different OS?

Comment: Here are the cx_Oracle installation instructions: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html  The 'other' machine will need Oracle client and the matching Visual Studio redistributable on it.

Comment: same OS.link is not working provided by you. could you please provide latest link

Comment: My exe file not working in another same machine which is using cx_oracle import statement.

Comment: same .exe file not working in another laptop with same configurations.